# Unknown error in the memory in C

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, memory-management

I have a 2D dynamic array.
I enter a line of 0's after line which has a biggest number:

```
void InsertZero(int **a, int pos){
    int i, j;
    a = (int**)realloc(a, n * sizeof(*a));
    a[n-1] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(**a));
    d = 0;
    for(i = n-1; i > pos; i--){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            a[i][j] = a[i-1][j];
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[pos][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

If i make a size of array 3, 5, 7, 9, ... it works correctly. But if a number of lines is 2, 4, 6, ... , it is an access violation error, when i try to print my array:

```
void Print(void){
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < (n-d); i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

code: http://codepad.org/JcUis6W4

Comment: Let's talk about the error in a little bit more detail, Sergey. What is the output you get and what is the output you expect?

Comment: i get an access violation error, when i try to read a[0][0] and my array consists of 2,4,6,8,... rows and coloms

Comment: It looks to me that you never initialize any a entry apart a[n-1]. So I don't know where you set n, and where you call InsertZero, but I assume you need to look into that direction or post that code here.

Comment: "d" i use when i have "n-1" rows and "n" cols, but after i insert new row, i have "n" row and cols.
code: http://codepad.org/JcUis6W4

Comment: Which call to Print fails?  The first call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this I cannot make sense of.... Look at comment 1, you have `n` set somewhere to `realloc` a block of memory which `a` is of type `int **` - a double pointer, how are you calling this function? Secondly, comment 2, Why did you call `calloc` when the `realloc` on a double pointer was called previously...? Assume `n` has value of 5, then, `realloc` is called on double pointer `a`, meaning `a[0][1]..a[4][1]`, now `calloc` is called thus `a[4]` has a new block of memory...

```
void InsertZero(int **a, int pos){
    int i, j;

    /* 1. */
    a = (int**)realloc(a, n * sizeof(*a)); 
    /* Bzzzzt....if realloc failed, a gets overwritten! */

    /* 2. */
    a[n-1] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(**a));

    /* 3. */
    d = 0;

    /* 4. */
    for(i = n-1; i > pos; i--){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++){
            a[i][j] = a[i-1][j];
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a[pos][i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment 3, what is `d` used for - useless variable?
Comment 4, you are under the presumption that the block of memory has array subscripts `[0][0]` to `[4][4]` if `n` had a value of 5!

Can you clarify all this?

**Edit:** Looking at it again... it is likely that `a` got overwritten when the call to `realloc` failed! I recommend this section of code to counteract this

```
    int **tmpA;
    tmpA = (int**)realloc(a, n * sizeof(*a)); 
    if (tmpA != NULL){
        a = tmpA;
        ....
        a[n-1] = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(**a));
        for(i = n-1; i > pos; i--){
            .... 
        }

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1) "a" have "n-1" elements, i make "n" elements with realloc
2)a[n-1] i call a new memory.
3) i have a "n-1" row and "n" cols. "d"=1, (n-d) is (n-1). When I add a new row, i make d=0 and "n" rows and "n" cols
4) i know that

Answer (score 0):

In your function `InsertZero` you have a local variable `a`. This local variable is initially set with a the address of a pointer to an integer (you probably wanted the address of a pointer to an array of integers, i.e. `int ***a`).

When you call `realloc` you are assigning your local copy of `a` a pointer to a block of memory, however once you have finished with your function it is entirely possible for your local copy of `a` to be pointing somewhere different to the rest of your program. You probably wanted to say `*a = (int **)realloc(a, n * sizeof(int *));`.

Dangerously, you're using `n` which isn't passed to your function. It appears you've made the assumption that `n` is going to be 1 bigger than the previous size of the array - otherwise your call to `calloc` is superfluous and you are just rotating the array letting the last element drop off as a memory leak.

Let's use a simpler example with no arrays, no dimensions. Let's say you wanted to create a function:

```
void make_me_a_pointer( int **mynumber ) {
    *mynumber = (int *)malloc( sizeof(int) );
    **mynumber = 7; /* assign the value 7 to my allocated memory */
}

int main( void ) {
    int *demoint;
    make_me_a_pointer( &demoint );
    printf( "Magic num is %d\n", *demoint );
}
```

However in your case you merely assigned `a = realloc`... and thus never communicated the new address of `a` outside your function.

Comment: Try writing some simple test code, Sergey, to allow yourself to familiarise with pointers before jumping into the deep end with multi-dimensional arrays and memory allocation...

Comment: PP has the right idea.  In Sergey's program, arr, n, and d are globals.  arr is assigned the pointer to the array of pointers allocated in CreateArray(), but as PP points out, later when you realloc, you never assign the result to the global arr.  I'm guessing that when n is even, realloc has to move the block elsewhere, so arr winds up pointing to memory that has been freed.

You must check the return from *alloc.  This call can fail and return NULL.  You program should handle that, perhaps by ending with an error message.  Use meaningful variable names, and avoid the use of globals.